# Narrowing the strip the cursor must be in to become a window resizing arrow in Win10?

Tags: windows-10

I'm using Win10Pro, version 1903. When I move the cursor to within a thick strip on the outside of a window (for example a Firefox, Notepad, Skype or folder window), it changes to a double-headed resizing arrow. The only side of a window where I don't get this behaviour, and where the cursor only changes to a resizer when it's actually on the rim of the window, is the top. Near all the other three sides it stays as a resizer until it's about 3/4 of an inch away from the window's edge on the outside.

How can I stop this behaviour so that the cursor behaves near every side of a window the same way it is currently behaving near the top?

Comment: This is new (and likely ongoing) Windows 10 behavior. You might consider adapting to it as it becomes very easy to manage. I use V1903 and Insider V1909 and both are like this

Comment: The first thing I do when I install Windows is set about fixing all the annoyances. This one was very easy to fix thanks to Harrymc's kind advice. I'd find it very irritating to see what's in a window or on the desktop but not to be able to act on it in the normal way because that area of the screen is reserved for changing the size of another window. For me that would kind of defeat the purpose of having a graphical UI based on windows. If I click on part of a window sticking out from behind another window I want the window I've clicked on to be brought to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires registry changes:

- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics`
- Double-click the value `PaddedBorderWidth`, set its value to `0` and click OK
- Reboot

In case of problems, you may reset it back to the default value of `-60`.

Comment: Excellent - many thanks for this. It worked a treat!